# Create four 3x3 sub-windows from a 5x5 window

Tags: image, matlab, filter, pixel

I understand that the loops should not be nested but I have done the same to further sub-divide the 5x5 window into four 3x3 sub-windows. Please help me with this, how to sub divide the 5x5 window into four 3x3 sub-windows without nested loop.

Code:

> for i=1:m

for j=1:n

```
  if(i<=(m-4) && j<=(n-4))

      % Reading 5 x 5 window in an image

v=1; 
for p=i:i+4
    u=1;
    for q=j:j+4
        P(v,u)=L(p,q);
        u=u+1;
    end
    v=v+1;
end

    % Sub dividing the 5 x 5 window into four 3x3 sub windows 

k=1;
for r=1:3
    l=1;
    for s=1:3
        v2(k,l)=P(r,s);
        v1(k,l)=P(r,s+2);   
        v3(k,l)=P(r+2,s);
        v4(k,l)=P(r+2,s+2);
        l=l+1;    
    end
    k=k+1;
end
```

I need this four vector v1,v2,v3 and v4 for further processing. Link of my previous question about retaining the corner pixels:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793103/retain-corner-pixels-in-an-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me tell a bit more than just answering your question on sub-dividing your window.

1. You read in a 5x5 window from an image like this:

   `P=L(i:(i+4),j:(j+4));`

   so that `(i,j)` is the top-left corner of the window on the original image.
2. This "sub-division" looks for me like taking a 3x3 starting from the TL, TR, BL and BR(*) corner of the 5x5 window. That can be done simply like this:

   `tl = P(1:3, 1:3); % this is v2 in your question`
   `tr = P(1:3, 3:5); % this is v1 (didn't you mix up v2 and v1 by any chance?)`
   `bl = P(3:5, 1:3); % this is v3`
   `br = P(3:5, 3:5); % this is v4`

   I suggest rather using this `tl, tr, bl, br` instead of `v1, v2, v3, v4` because it is more expressive.

(*)(T=top, B=bottom, L=left, R=right)

---

UPDATE:  (how to change the loops?)
You want to cover all the windows on L, so the first window will be `P=L(1:5, 1:5)`, the last will be `P=L((m-4):m,(n-4):n)`. All the others will be in between. So the first value of i is i=1, the last is i=m-4 and the first j is j=1, the last is j=n-4.

You can also verify this manually, typing a demo L into the command prompt of matlab, like this:

```
L=reshape([1:42], 6, 7); % a 6x6 test array
m=6; n=7;

i=1; j=1;
P_first=L(i:(i+4),j:(j+4)); % should contain 1

i=m-4; j=n-4;
P_last=L(i:(i+4),j:(j+4)); % should contain 42
```

Comment: Once thank you very much Barnabas Szabolcs, you saved my day. I will try this out and let you know.

Comment: I receive the following error:                                      ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> PRM1 at 45
      P=L(i:(i+4),j:(j+5));

Comment: I've corrected the typo. As for your problem: your for loop must not go to m and n, but `for i=1:(m-4)` and `for j=1:(n-4)`.

Comment: thanks it's working... but why it should go for i=1:(m-4) and for j=1:(n-4) not as in original code stated in question that is from to m and n ( for i=1:m and for j=1:n). Please explain..

Comment: Please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816591/formation-of-clusters-in-matlab

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if this is what you need, but how about this solution:

```
% Some random matrices that are each one third the length and width of the total
LU3 = rand(10);
LM3 = rand(10);
LD3 = rand(10);
MU3 = rand(10);
MM3 = rand(10);
MD3 = rand(10);
RU3 = rand(10);
RM3 = rand(10);
RD3 = rand(10);

% Putting them together
I = [LU3 MU3 RU3;LM3 MM3 RM3;LD3 MD3 RD3];

% Splitting it up in four parts
LU2 = I(1:15,1:15)
RU2 = I(16:30,1:15)
LD2 = I(1:15,16:)
RD2 = I(16:30,16:30)
```

It is not very generalized but it should not be hard to adapt.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Actually I've just noticed that you're working on a 30-by-30 matrix while the question is about a 5-by-5 matrix...

Comment: @EitanT The size is indeed different, but apparently I misinterpreted the meaning of 'window' and 'sub window'. As there already is an accepted answer I will just leave it at this.

Comment: @Dennis Jaheruddin , Can u look over the error i stated in the accepted answer ? I receive the following error: ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions. Error in ==> PRM1 at 45 P=L(i:(i+4),j:(j+5));

Comment: @EitanT Can u look over the error i stated in the accepted answer ? I receive the following error: ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions. Error in ==> PRM1 at 45 P=L(i:(i+4),j:(j+5));